# How adaptive threshold calculate the threshold of the pixel?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, adaptive-threshold

I want to know how adaptive threshold calculates the threshold value for each pixel either in Adaptive mean or Adaptive Gaussian ?

opencv library
cv2.adaptivethreshold()

Comment: Which adaptive threshold? There are millions of implementations, they all make different choices. We don’t know what program you’re looking at.

Comment: opencv library
cv2.adaptivethreshold

Comment: OpenCV is open-source software. Why don’t you look at the source code?